# Считывание с клавиатуры в метод

Tags: java, java-8

Помогите пожалуйста! Только недавно начала изучать программирование и не могу понять такую вещь: 
с клавиатуры вводятся 3 точки треугольника и еще одна точка Р. Нужно определить, принадлежит ли точка треугольнику. 
Я ввела числа с клавиутуры, а как обратиться к ним в методе не знаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Методы гет и сет прописаны в классе треугольник

Comment: Замените картинку в вопросе кодом как текст.

Comment: ваше условие задачи, а тем более код не дает возможности дать какой-либо ответ. что такое "три точки треугольника"? и что значит "принадлежит треугольнику"? из этого, как минимум, можно сделать вывод, что треугольник один и точка одна, а вы, судя по коду, создаете 4 экземпляра класса Traingle, т.е. по сути 4 треугольника. Что в этом самом классе тоже загадка. Сформулируйте точно задание и покажите Ваш код, а мы поможем его отредактировать

Answer (score 1):

То есть "обратиться"?
Вы же в коде используете point.getX() и т.д.
Если нужно обраться к этим точкам в постороннем методе, то нужно либо передать эти точки в сам метод:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    inTriangle(point.getX(), point.getY(), a.getX(), a.get(Y) /*И т.д.*/  );
}

public static boolean inTriangle(double a, double b, double c, double p /*И т.д.*/) {
    //Тут код расчётов
}
```

Либо можно назначить переменные в классе, тогда к ним можно будет обращаться даже не из главного метода:

```
public static Triangle point, a, b, c;
public static void Main(String[] args) {
   point = new Trianle();
   a = new Triangle();
   b = new Triangle();
   c = new Triangle();
   //Код считывания чисел с клавиатуры...
}

public static boolean inTriangle() {
    point.getX();
    //Тут код расчётов
}
```